# Django-Snowflake external Browser connection issue when hosting in IIS Server

Tags: python, django, iis, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have connected Snowflake from Django using authenticator as external browser.But when I hosted the application in IIS Server am not able to connect snowflake, Its not going for external browser and showing error like this

> HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
> C:\TESTCASE_AUTOMATION-PYTHON-featue_UI\venv\Scripts\python.exe - The
> FastCGI process exceeded configured request timeout

Answer (score 0):

Please check applicationHost.config file and search entry for whether its available there or not, if not then set. finally restart the server.

> C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config

```
<fastCgi>
   <application fullPath="C:\TESTCASE_AUTOMATION-PYTHON-featue_UI\venv\Scripts\python.exe idleTimeout="900" activityTimeout="180" requestTimeout="10000" instanceMaxRequests="10000" />
</fastCgi>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,But I have successfully hosted app. But when the snowflake connection module only having this problem.Snowflake authentication in external browser.

Comment: This is an iis error and has nothing to do with snowflakes. You can try to troubleshoot from the iis side.